# Dynamic styles in Openlayers.js

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson, vector, vector-layer

I create wfs vector layers in loop:

```
 for(var i=0; i<vectors.length;i++)  {   
                 var styles = {
                            'Point': new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                    radius: vectors[i].pointRadius,
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointStrokeColor
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointFillColor
                                    })
                                })
                            }),
                            'MultiPoint': new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                    radius: vectors[i].pointRadius,
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointStrokeColor
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointFillColor
                                    })
                                })
                            }),
                            'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].lineColor,
                                    width: vectors[i].lineWidth
                                })
                            }),
                            'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].multiLineColor,
                                    width: vectors[i].multiLineWidth
                                })
                            }),
                            'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].polygonStrokeColor,
                                    lineDash: [vectors[i].polygonStrokeLineDash],
                                    width: vectors[i].polygonStrokeWidth
                                }),
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color:vectors[i].polygonFillColor
                                })
                            }),
                            'MultiPolygon': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].multiPolygonStrokeColor,
                                    width: vectors[i].multiPolygonStrokeWidth,
                                }),
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: vectors[i].multiPolygonFillColor
                                })
                            })
                        };
                        var styleFunction = function (feature) {
                            return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
                        }
                        overlays.push(
                              new ol.layer.Vector({
                                    visible:vectors[i].isDefault,
                                    title: vectors[i].name,
                                    style: styleFunction,
                                    source:new ol.source.Vector({
                                       format:new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                                         featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"}),
                                    url:vectors[i].url
                            })}));
}
```

After that I add overlays array of vector to map and styles don't work. All vectors have style from last vector in array. How make difference vector style?

Answer (score 1):

Declare styles and style function outside the loop as arrays and feed them inside the loop. Something like that should do the trick. I have not test it. Some adjustment may need to take place.

```
var styles = new Array();
var styleFunction = new Array();
 for(var i=0; i<vectors.length;i++)  {   
                 styles[i] =  {
                            'Point': new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                    radius: vectors[i].pointRadius,
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointStrokeColor
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointFillColor
                                    })
                                })
                            }),
                            'MultiPoint': new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                    radius: vectors[i].pointRadius,
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointStrokeColor
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: vectors[i].pointFillColor
                                    })
                                })
                            }),
                            'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].lineColor,
                                    width: vectors[i].lineWidth
                                })
                            }),
                            'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].multiLineColor,
                                    width: vectors[i].multiLineWidth
                                })
                            }),
                            'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].polygonStrokeColor,
                                    lineDash: [vectors[i].polygonStrokeLineDash],
                                    width: vectors[i].polygonStrokeWidth
                                }),
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color:vectors[i].polygonFillColor
                                })
                            }),
                            'MultiPolygon': new ol.style.Style({
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: vectors[i].multiPolygonStrokeColor,
                                    width: vectors[i].multiPolygonStrokeWidth,
                                }),
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: vectors[i].multiPolygonFillColor
                                })
                            })
                        };
                        styleFunction[i]  = function (feature) {
                            return styles[i][feature.getGeometry().getType()];
                        }
                        overlays.push(
                              new ol.layer.Vector({
                                    visible:vectors[i].isDefault,
                                    title: vectors[i].name,
                                    style: styleFunction[i],
                                    source:new ol.source.Vector({
                                       format:new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                                         featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"}),
                                    url:vectors[i].url
                            })}));
}
```

Comment: I tried yours code and got that "TypeError: styles[i] is undefined"/

Answer (score 0):

I change loop from "for" to "forEach" and everything is ok!